# Unity c# task, managing arrays

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I just started a new masters to boost my career and I'm learning c# from scratch for Unity 3D game programming.
I was given my first weekly assignment and I'm pretty lost as to what I should be doing. I was asked to create an array of any kind and with a switch be able to add one element or delete one element from the array. I have managed to print to log my initial array, then switch to add case and add one element to the index, but the problem I'm having is that I only manage to add one to the array once. after that the auxiliary array I re create resets to only add one any time I go back inside the add case. If you could help me out with some pointer it'd be great.

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EjercicioSemanal_01 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum manageEnum {None, Add, Delete};
    public manageEnum enumValue;
    public int[] array = new int[5] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int[] newArray = new int[5];

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        switch (enumValue)
        {
            case manageEnum.None:
                if (newArray.Length > array.Length)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < newArray.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Debug.Log(newArray[i]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
                    {
                        Debug.Log(array[j]);
                    }
                }

                break;
            case manageEnum.Add:
                int itemToAdd = 0;
                newArray = new int[array.Length + 1];
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    newArray[i] = array[i];
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < newArray.Length; j++)
                {
                    Debug.Log(newArray[j]);
                }
                break;
            case manageEnum.Delete:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new array stored in `newarray` in the `Add` case but you aren taking the data from `array`. You must replace `array` with `newarray` if you want the changes to be updated in `array`:

```
case manageEnum.Add:
        int itemToAdd = 0;
        newArray = new int[array.Length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            newArray[i] = array[i];
        }

        //replace old array with new array
        array = newArray;

        for (int j = 0; j < newArray.Length; j++)
        {
            Debug.Log(newArray[j]);
        }
        break;
```

Also, there is a better way to do that, you can use `Array.Resize`

```
 case manageEnum.Add:

     Array.Resize(ref array, array.Length + 1);
     //now array has one item more, no need of an intermediate array.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like at some stage you would like to add `itemToAdd` to an existing array. In which case I would just modify your code slightly:

```
        case manageEnum.Add:
            int itemToAdd = 0;
            var tempArray = new int [ array.Length + 1 ];
            for ( var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++ )
                tempArray [ i ] = array [ i ];
            tempArray [ array.Length ] = itemToAdd;
            array = tempArray;

            for ( var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++ )
                Debug.Log( array [ i ] );
            break;
```

There's also no need for a class level temporary array (newArray). We're creating a new one in the case block, so we might as well define it there.

In the same vein, we could then look at the Delete case:

```
        case manageEnum.Delete:
            var newArraySize = array.Length - 1;
 
            // Option 1. The brute force way.
            var tempArray = new int [ newArraySize  ];
            for ( var i = 0; i < newArraySize ; i++ )
                tempArray [ i ] = array [ i ];

            // Option 2. The single line way.
            Array.Resize ( ref array, newArraySize );
 
            array = tempArray;

            for ( var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++ )
                Debug.Log( array [ i ] );
            break;
```

In the above Delete block, you'd use one or the other of the options. If you don't remove, the code would actually still work, as trying to resize an array to the same size won't actually do anything... but, please, remove one or the other of the options.